# Родительный падеж + количество

Tags: падежи, род

Скажите, пожалуйста, как объясняется тот факт, что при использовании количества, больше одного, подлежащее становится дополнением (если это правильно) и переходит в родительный падеж.

В нашей комании работают сотрудники (Именит)

В нашей компании работает один сотрудник (Именит)

В нашей компании работает сто сотрудников (Род)

Единственное объяснение, которое я нашла по аналогии это сходство с Genetivus partitivus в Латыни, но не знаю, правильно ли оно.

Спасибо!

(вопрос появился в связи с курсом русского языка learnrussian.rt.com)

Comment: "В нашей компании работает двадцать один сотрудник" - больше одного, не родительный падеж.

Comment: The way it was explained to me is that один is singular counter, even as part of a larger number as Artemix pointed out; два (две) три четыре are partitive counters comparable to  expressions like "a pair of glasses" "a cup of tea" and thus take a singular genitive; and the numbers from пять up are collective partitive counters, comparable to "много" "большинство" and thus take a genitive plural. This association has really helped me deal with them.

Comment: This is same explanation I gave and it fits for romance language native speakers. Seems, it helps to remember, but actually, it's not the reason, as Shady_arc has explained in next comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правило немного другое. Нужно посмотреть, на какое *слово* оканчивается ваше число.

Дальше, если вам нужно число + объект в форме именительного падежа (именительный или винительный для неодушевлённых), то

- **...один** — использовать *именительный падеж, ед.ч*
- **... два(две)/три/четыре** — использовать *родительный падеж ед.ч*
- **... пять/шесть/...десять/одиннадцать/...сто/тысяча/миллион...*** — использовать *родительный падеж мн.ч.*

Объяснение, если на пальцах, достаточно простое (я не лингвист, поэтому совершенно научно вряд ли объясню). В русском маленькие числа были прилагательными, а пять и больше — существительными. Сравните: *полная кровать **яблок**/ куча **яблок**/ пять **яблок*** — аналогия тут очевидна

Усложняется дело тем, что когда-то в славянских языках было двойственное число. Это сейчас его не осталось почти ни в одном. Соответственно, если бы мы до сих пор так говорили, система была бы примерно такой:

- один стол (ИМ.п, ед.ч)
- два стола (ИМ.п, дв.ч)
- три/четыре столы (ИМ.п, мн.ч)
- пять столов (РОД.п, мн.ч)

  *(это ИМИТАЦИЯ из слов современного русского — уверяю вас, с точки зрения истории это 100% вранье! Помните, что в древнерусском склонения по падежам были другие, а окончание "-ов" — редкая диковинка, которая была лишь для одного типа существительных мужского рода; в древнерусском было правильно говорить "пять конь", "много стол")*

Дальше происходит любопытное: в процессе развития двойственное число пропадает почти во всех славянских языках. Встаёт вопрос, что делать с 2,3,4, которые используют разные формы, одна из которых ныне противоречит логике языка. У нас при этом двойственное число подменяется родительным падежом единственного, потому что формы у ряда мужских существительных похожи.

И тут одни языки решают использовать "три/четыре" прямо как два ("три стола"), а другие — использовать "два" по аналогии с "три/четыре" ("два столы"). Мы попали в первую группу.

Собственно, и вся история.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно. У вас нет под рукой ссылок или названия книг, где есть объяснения, я нашла только статью в вики-адвансд, но она немного путанная.